# array_merge removes my duplicates

Tags: php, arrays

I am adding several arrays to a `$result` array.

Find below my example what I am currently doing:

```
$res = array();

$arr1 = array("key1" => array("10","12"));
$arr2 = array("key2" => array("1","11"));
$arr3 = array("key1" => array("10","12"));
$arr4 = array("key2" => array("1","11"));

$res = array_merge($res, $arr1);
$res = array_merge($res, $arr2);
$res = array_merge($res, $arr3);
$res = array_merge($res, $arr4);

print_r($res);

// OUTPUT:
// #######
Array
(
    [key1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 12
        )

    [key2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 11
        )

)
```

However, I would like to have the following output:

```
Array
(
    [key1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 12
        )

    [key2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 11
        )
    [key1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 12
        )

    [key2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 11
        )

)
```

As you can see I would like to add the duplicated arrays to my result array.

Any suggestions why array_merge replaces the duplicated merges and how to turn this behavior of?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: You can't have two or more identical keys in the same array. The last one will overwrite the others.

Comment: @Mehdi Thank you for your reply! Is there another function to have two or more identical arrays in an array?

Comment: @Anna.Klee Think about it this way, how would you reference/access them individually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented the answer is no.  A key is inherently unique.  PHP uses the key to locate the associated value.

You can not accomplish the structure you want, but if all you want is to have all the values in one array structure you could accomplish that simply with this code:

```
$res = array();

$res[] = array("key1" => array("10","12"));
$res[] = array("key2" => array("1","11"));
$res[] = array("key1" => array("10","12"));
$res[] = array("key2" => array("1","11"));

var_dump($res);
// You'll see all your arrays in one structure
```

Answer (score 2):

This was meant to be a comment but ended up being too long.

You need to understand how arrays work, this is just a brief small explanation.
Let's say you have an array:

```
$array = array(
    'key1' => 'Hello ',
    'key2' => 'World',
    'key1' => 'Foo ',
    'key2' => 'Bar',
);
```

Now we try to use it like this:

```
echo $array['key1'].$array['key2'];
```

If we can use identical keys, which one will be printed?
`Hello world` or `Foo bar`? or a mix?

The real output is `Foo bar` because the last two will overwrite the first ones.

[Here](https://nikic.github.io/2012/03/28/Understanding-PHPs-internal-array-implementation.html) is a more detailed (and advanced) article explaining how PHP handles arrays.